# Shortened mp4 renders 3x larger file than the original file

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, eevee-render-engine

I have a 12mb mp4 that I have imported, deleted sound, made shorter in the VSE, increased speed to make shorter again, and rendered out as mp4 using default settings. The rendered mp4 is 39mb! Why would it increase so much?

Comment: FFMPEG (in Blender) can write many mp4 codecs with [various encoder and quality settings](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).